# heroku fails to install pytables, error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5

Tags: heroku, hdf5, pytables

after folowwing the Get Started for Python on Heroku, I would like to add some packages which  I installed locally without problems (Win10,Python 3.7).
One of these packages is pytables.
When I try to install the pytables package in heroku ,it fails with the following error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5

Is there a way I can verify if HDF5 available on my dyno?

c:\Temp\python-getting-started>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 301 bytes | 301.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.1
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting tables (from -r /tmp/build_2935f6f96f28f37f686b7fbf4fc38a83/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/53/8f34ce887c2a2ad80518980419a5f6f41defc85a287a355987e559ce9385/tables-3.4.4.tar.gz (4.6MB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            * Using Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug  1 2018, 21:17:03)
remote:            * USE_PKGCONFIG: True
remote:            /tmp/H5closevpxwstk_.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
remote:             main (int argc, char **argv) {
remote:             ^~~~
remote:            /tmp/H5closevpxwstk_.c: In function ‘main’:
remote:            /tmp/H5closevpxwstk_.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘H5close’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
remote:                 H5close();
remote:                 ^~~~~~~
remote:            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
remote:            collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
remote:            .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
remote:               You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
remote:               library can be found by setting the `HDF5_DIR` environment
remote:               variable or by using the `--hdf5` command-line option.
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-k24wiesz/tables/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to fierce-basin-65098.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/fierce-basin-65098.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fierce-basin-65098.git'

Comment: pytables has dependency on hdf5 and numpy. conda package manager for anaconda or miniconda distro handles this for me. I'm not familiar with heroku. Does it manage dependencies, or do you have to do it? You can try installing hdf5 package first, then pytables again.

Comment: It's my first experience with Heroku. As this is a PAAS model. Maybe they have a conda distro I can deploy. I will verify this. I cannot install the hdf5 packages neither.

Comment: Looking at the Heroku site, they start start by installing the packager manager `Chocolatey`. Python is installed with the command `choco install python`. Is that how you installed Python? From there you need `Pipenv`. It is a dependency manager for Python. It looks like you you should use `pipenv install pkg_name` to install Python packages. All the details here: [link](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref)

Comment: They use pip as dependency manager. I need to add the packages in a file called, requirements.txt and when I run git push heroku master, all my code will be deployed and the packages which are mentioned in the requirement.txt will be installed. Except one package , called tables :-(
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app
Anyway, I can install an alternative h5py and I will try to adapt my code and work with this one.
Thanks for your help!